# U1077 Error running nmake on live555

Tags: shell, visual-studio-2015, nmake, live555

Trying to build live555 for windows. I've followed instructions (http://tujv.bitbucket.org/2016/02/building-live555/) and generated make files.

When running this command:

```
nmake /B -f liveMedia.mak
```

It outputs this:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl" -c -Iinclude -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include    -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" Media.cpp
"C:\Program" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

It says "C:\Program" is not recognized as command.

Normally it would say that when the path with spaces doesn't have quotes, but there are quotes here at the end of the path, I don't understand why it doesn't recognize it.

Here is the start of liveMedia.mak, where the path variable is set:

```
INCLUDES = -Iinclude -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include
PREFIX = /usr/local
LIBDIR = $(PREFIX)/lib
##### Change the following for your environment:
# Comment out the following line to produce Makefiles that generate debuggable code:
NODEBUG=1

# The following definition ensures that we are properly matching
# the WinSock2 library file with the correct header files.
# (will link with "ws2_32.lib" and include "winsock2.h" & "Ws2tcpip.h")
TARGETOS = WINNT

# If for some reason you wish to use WinSock1 instead, uncomment the
# following two definitions.
# (will link with "wsock32.lib" and include "winsock.h")
#TARGETOS = WIN95
#APPVER = 4.0

#!include    <ntwin32.mak>

UI_OPTS =       $(guilflags) $(guilibsdll)
# Use the following to get a console (e.g., for debugging):
CONSOLE_UI_OPTS =       $(conlflags) $(conlibsdll)
CPU=i386

TOOLS32 =       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
COMPILE_OPTS =      $(INCLUDES) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) -I. -I"$(TOOLS32)\include"
C =         c
C_COMPILER =        "$(TOOLS32)\bin\cl"
C_FLAGS =       $(COMPILE_OPTS)
CPP =           cpp
CPLUSPLUS_COMPILER =    $(C_COMPILER)
CPLUSPLUS_FLAGS =   $(COMPILE_OPTS)
```

If someone sees the error, or a way to work around it, I would be very thankful

Thanks in advance

Comment: try dbl-quoting the path/prog value for `TOOLS32 = ` ? Good luck.

Comment: You mean like that: TOOLS32 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC" ? Cause that gives another error

Comment: what is the error msg? Good luck.

Comment: a worse error, just sintax error or something like that, cause it tries executing ""C:\Prog.....\VC"\bin\cl" which doesn't make sense